# How to override existing java library or specify exact version to use

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle-adf, webcenter

I'm using ADF Framework withing webcenter suite 11.1.1.5, that happened to have bundled Apache POI libraries version 3.5.
However current project requires at least 3.7, or even latest version of this library.

I have weblogic server, with predeployed webcenter application and all required libraries for it.

If I bundle Apache POI library version 3.8 inside my project, it gets deployed along, however application still use version 3.5.

Webcenter libraries deployed earler and I can't change this behavior. Is there a way to override it at least for my application, beside including sources of Apache POI in my project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how it is going in weblogic but I can recommend you to take a look in class loaders configuration. As far as I remember there was some kind of class loaders order configuration when deploying web application. Generally you should ask it to use the application level class path first and then use the application server library classes. Open the weblogic administration console and try to find this configuration.

Comment: Thank you, didn't find solution yet, but it seems that its the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

AlexR was pointing in the right way and there are actually several solution to this problem.
1. Install POI libraries into $DOMAIN_HOME/lib/ and restart the server. This is system class path and if you ain't configured otherwise it will override other sources.
This solution is easy, but won't work for all of the cases.
2. Second solution is to use filtering class loader feature, that will change standard lookup from system->application->web to filtering->application->web.
More details are available at https://blogs.oracle.com/jamesbayer/entry/sharing_a_class_with_a

In short, you can use adminserver:port:/wls-cat (Classloader Analysis Tool) to identify possible class conflict and inspect current classloader configuration and then use gathered info to add to weblogic-application.xml in your application to enable filtering class loader feature. For example, you can add: "org.apache.poi.*" to the filter causing classloader to check your application libs first. And this configuration will affect only current application, so you won't break other applications, that may require old/different version of the old library.

Answer (score 1):

You can try look at weblogic-application.xml file (put in META-INF). In this file it is possible to specify which classes should be loaded from application lib folder and not from weblogic.

Example:

`<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>`

(this will load log4j from application lib, not weblogic log4j library)